# Authentication in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache );
        Response.Cache.SetAllowResponseInBrowserHistory(false);
    }
```

This code i have used to authenticate the website,its working but only when the user copies the url and paste it in a new window,but opening in the new window leads to the next page without any login credentials.

Comment: Why aren't you using the built in authentication?  It forces a user to be authenticated before you even get to the Page_Load method.

Comment: Question is not clear.  What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For authentication:
In `page_Load` Events

```
if (session(user_id) != null) {
  response.redirect("the_page_which_you_want_to_go.aspx");
} else {
  response.redirect("Login.aspx");
}
```

Comment: Please use SO's code formatting, it will make your answers far clearer.